# commandClass setter methods are not invoked while implementing SimpleFormController in spring 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, sakai

commandClass setter methods are not invoked while implementing SimpleFormController in spring 3.x, Calling getter method on command odject returns null value.

- uploadMessageBundle.jsp

  ```
  <div class="instruction">
      <spring:message code="messagebundle.upload.instruction"/>
  </div>


  <form method="post" action="uploadMessageBundle.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
  <spring:bind path="command.locale">
      <select name="${status.expression}">
          <c:forEach var="locale" items="${locales}" varStatus="status">
              <option value="${locale}">${locale}</option>
          </c:forEach>
      </select>
  </spring:bind>
      <br/>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td class="form_text"></td>
              <td>
                  <input type="submit" name="_target1" class="active" value="<spring:message code='messagebundle.upload'  />"/>
                  <input type="submit" name="_cancel" value="<spring:message code='messagebundle.cancle'/>"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  <jsp:directive.include file="/templates/footer.jsp"/>
  ```
- UploadMessageBundleController.java

  ```
  package org.sakaiproject.adminmessagebundle.tool;

  import org.sakaiproject.messagebundle.api.MessageBundleService;
  import org.sakaiproject.messagebundle.api.MessageBundleProperty;
  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
  import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
  import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder;
  import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.*;

  public class UploadMessageBundleController extends AbstractUploadController {

      MessageBundleService messageBundleService;

      protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
          Map map = new HashMap();
          map.put("locales",messageBundleService.getLocales());
          return map;
      }

      protected void doSubmitAction(Object command) throws Exception {

          try {
          setCommandClass(FileUploadBean.class);
          setCommandName("command");
          setSuccessView("messageBundleHome");
          setFormView("uploadMessageBundle");
          FileUploadBean fileUploadBean = (FileUploadBean) command;
          List properties = new ArrayList();
          InputStream myxls = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileUploadBean.getFile());
          HSSFWorkbook wb     = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
          HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);       // first sheet
          int rows = 0;
          boolean foundHeaderRow = false;

          for (Iterator i =sheet.rowIterator();i.hasNext();)
          {
              HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) i.next();
              if ("module".equals(row.getCell((short)0).getStringCellValue())) {
                  foundHeaderRow = true;
                  continue;
              }
              if (foundHeaderRow) {
                  MessageBundleProperty mbp = new MessageBundleProperty();
                  mbp.setModuleName(row.getCell((short)0).getStringCellValue());
                  mbp.setBaseName(row.getCell((short)1).getStringCellValue());
                  mbp.setPropertyName(row.getCell((short)2).getStringCellValue());
                  mbp.setValue(row.getCell((short)3).getStringCellValue());
                  mbp.setLocale(fileUploadBean.getLocale());

                   //TODO allow an optional 5 column for new translations
                  properties.add(mbp);

                  rows++;
              }
          }
          if (foundHeaderRow == false) {
              throw new Exception("Invalid excel file, can't find header row");
          }
          fileUploadBean.setRows(messageBundleService.importProperties(properties));

          }catch(Exception e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
      }
          }

      protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
          // when done, redirect to the main page and specify the "command" http parameter
          ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
          FileUploadBean fileUploadBean = (FileUploadBean) command;
          if (isCancel(request)) {
              modelAndView = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), "command", "list");
              modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Upload Cancelled");
          } else {
              try {
                  doSubmitAction(command);
                  modelAndView = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), "command", "list");
                  modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Upload " + fileUploadBean.getRows() + " properties for locale " + fileUploadBean.getLocale());
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  modelAndView = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), "command", "list");
                  Map model = modelAndView.getModel();
                  model.put("error", ex.getMessage());
                  logger.warn("",ex);
              }
          }
          return modelAndView;
      }

      protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder)
          throws ServletException {
          // to actually be able to convert Multipart instance to byte[]
          // we have to register a custom editor
          binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());
          // now Spring knows how to handle multipart object and convert them
      }

      public void setMessageBundleService(MessageBundleService messageBundleService) {
          this.messageBundleService = messageBundleService;
      }

  }
  ```

** bean configuration in xml file**

```
<bean id="uploadMessageBundleController" class="org.sakaiproject.adminmessagebundle.tool.UploadMessageBundleController">
            <property name="messageBundleService"><ref bean="org.sakaiproject.messagebundle.api.MessageBundleService"/></property>
            <property name="commandClass" value="org.sakaiproject.adminmessagebundle.tool.FileUploadBean"/>
            <property name="commandName" value="command"/>
            <property name="formView" value="uploadMessageBundle"/>
            <property name="successView" value="redirect:messageBundleHome.htm"/>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed following bean definition in .xml file, so it was unable to call setter method in commandClass for file uploaded in the form.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```